# Can't add likes to the fields param

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

According to the Facebook Graph API [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), the `fields` param acts as a result mask:

> By default, most object properties are returned when you make a query.
>   You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the
>   "fields" query parameter.

Indeed, this works fine for most fields. For instance, `/7354446700?fields=name,picture` returns:

```
{
  "name": "Grooveshark", 
  "id": "7354446700", 
  "type": "page", 
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203560_7354446700_6819703_q.jpg"
}
```

However, for some reason, as soon as the `likes` field is added to the `fields` list, things break down. For instance, `/7354446700?fields=name,picture,likes` returns:

```
{
  "name": "Grooveshark", 
  "id": "7354446700", 
  "type": "page", 
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203560_7354446700_6819703_q.jpg", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ]
  }
}
```

Even more strange, if I omit the other two fields (`name` and `pictures`), sending only `likes`, I get

```
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ]
  }
}
```

The reason I find this extra-strange is because the "mandatory" fields (`id` and `type`) which should be added to every response are not included here (although they *were* included when `fields=name,picture,likes`).

What appears to be happening is that the `field=likes` parameter **appears to be misinterpreted as a Connections request** rather than simply a field mask, hence the `data` segment that normally appears when you'd call `/7354446700/likes`.

Is there a good reason for this? Is there any other way to get the `likes` field without fetching the entire object? I can't imagine this would be expected behavior, so I assume it is a bug, but I thought I'd ask here first before filing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed appears to be a bug; I've checked internally and there's an as yet unresolved task open to fix this issue which was reported to us in our bug tracker previously.

In the meantime, the default return value for a page will include the 'likes' field even if it cant be retrieved solely.

Comment: Any updates on this? Has it been resolved? Is there a link to a bug tracker I can follow?

Comment: As far as I know, the likes field is preferred over the likes connection now (i.e /PAGE_ID?fields=likes will return the like count, not the 'likes' connection) (e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?fields=likes)